# Python 3.4.4 application works but exe fails with utf-8 error

Tags: python, utf-8, runtime-error, exe

I created an exe from my Python application, which is a GUI that hooks up to a SQL database and allows the user to populate data with the fields. Running the Python script works fine by itself, but running the exe I get the error

`File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte`

This refers to the line `(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)`

I have already modified tokenize.py line 392 from

`line_string = line.decode('utf-8')` to
`line_string = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'` as suggested which removed the same error for that module, but now I get the same error for codec.py.

I can't use the same fix with this one. Is this a bug and is it easy to fix?

Comment: It seems you're trying to decode with UTF-8 a file that isn't encoded with UTF-8. Using the `errors="ignore"` strategy only mutes the (justified) exception at the cost of losing data – do you really want that? A clean solution means you make sure that `line.decode(<codec>)` matches the encoding of the file.

Comment: How can I find what my code is encoded with and how can I change this to be encoded with UTF-8? I've tried quite a few methods from other posts but none seem to work.

Comment: Just to add, the last line of the error log is `SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'J:\\Python_Scripts\\Python_Application_Testing_Briars\\dist\\BriarsNurseryApp.exe'`

Comment: For a .py script, you control the source code encodin through your editor/IDE and tell the Python interpreter about it through the `# coding: utf8` comment at the top of your script. For compiled .exe programs I don't know; you should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I have a Python script which is used for embedding the icon into the panel. I commented out the following which is used for backwards compatibility

`getBitmap = wx.deprecated(GetBitmap)
    getData = wx.deprecated(GetData)
    getIcon = wx.deprecated(GetIcon)
    getImage = wx.deprecated(GetImage)`

and it now works. I obtained this code from another site.